# Calcular diagonais de uma matriz usando Threads

Tags: c

Preciso de uma ajuda enorme. 
Preciso fazer um programa em C no qual calcule as diagonais de uma matriz usando Threads conforme o enunciados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme me orientaram, eu devo passar o valor da diagonal e do salto(mudança de diagonal) como parâmetros, mas não sei o que fazer com esses valores.

Segue o código que eu consegui fazer até agora (esta incompleto pois não sei como proceder na função para somar as diagonais):

OBS: tirei as funções que geram o arquivo com os valores da matriz e a função que atribui esses valores à matriz para o código ficar mais limpo e fácil de entender.

```
typedef struct{
    int diag=0;
    int salto;
}ST;

ST v;

struct param *arg;

void *somarMatriz(void *args){
    ST * in =  (ST *) args;

    int x=0, y=0;

    result = (float *) malloc((l+c-1)*sizeof(float));

    x=0;
    for(i=; i<l+c-1; i++){
        result[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=l-1; i>=0; i--){
        x = y;
        for(j=0; j<c; j++){
            result[x] += mat[i][j];
            x++;
        }
        y++;
    }

}


int main (){ 

    printf("Entre com o numero de linhas da matriz: \n");
    scanf("%d", &l);

    printf("Entre com o numero de colunas da matriz: \n");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    printf("Entre com o quantidade de Threads desejada:\n");
    scanf("%d", &arg.salto);

    gerarArquivo(l, c);
    gerarMatriz(l, c);

    pthread_t threads[T];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int rc;
    long t;
    void *status;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    for(t=0; t<T; t++){
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, somarMatriz, (void*)&v);
        if (rc){
            printf("ERRO");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit((void *)NULL);

    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Resultados:\n");
    for(i=0; i<l+c-1; i++){
        printf("%d\t", result[i]);
  }  

  printf("\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz o código a baixo usando API do windows, não deve ser muito difícil passar para pthreads. Outra solução (talvez mais eficiente), seria usar Thread Pool.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(void* data);

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
}PARAM;

int **matrix;
int *result;
int N, M, T;

int main()
{
    scanf_s("%d", &M);
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    scanf_s("%d", &T);

    int jobAmountLeft = M + N - 2;

    PARAM *param = (PARAM*) calloc(M+N-1, sizeof(PARAM));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++){
         param[i].x = 0;
         param[i].y = i;
    }
    for (; i < M + N - 1; i++) {
        param[i].x = i - M + 1;
        param[i].y = 0;
     }

    result = (int*)calloc(M + N - 1, sizeof(int));

    matrix = (int**)calloc(M, sizeof(int*));
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) matrix[i] = (int*) calloc(N, sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) 
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
            scanf_s("%d", &matrix[i][j]);

    HANDLE *thread = (HANDLE*)calloc(T, sizeof(HANDLE));

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        thread[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, &param[jobAmountLeft], 0, NULL);
        jobAmountLeft--;
        if(jobAmountLeft < 0) break;
     }

    while(jobAmountLeft >= 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            WaitForSingleObject(thread[i], 0.01);
            thread[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, &param[jobAmountLeft], 0, NULL);
            jobAmountLeft--;
            if(jobAmountLeft < 0) break;
         }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        WaitForSingleObject(thread[i], INFINITE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < M + N - 1; i++) {
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    }

    scanf_s("%d",&N);


 }

 DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(void* data) {
     PARAM *in = (PARAM*)data;
     int x = in->x;
     int y = in->y;
     int acc = 0;

     for(int i = y, j = x; i < M && j < N; j++, i++){
         acc += matrix[i][j];
     }

     result[M - in->y + in->x - 1] = acc;
     return 0;
 }
```

Para a função eu passo os índices do primeiro elemento de cada diagonal. Esses valores são os índices dos elementos da primeira coluna e da primeira linha

Comment: Nesse link tem um exemplo de como fazer Thread Pool em C:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357955/windows-api-thread-pool-simple-example